# Rspec / Capybara: Testing if a controller method is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, capybara

Given I set up a HomeController with an index action

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

and routed to it via the root path,

```
  root :to => "home#index"
```

why does this request spec fail

```
it 'should called the home#index action' do
    HomeController.should_receive(:index)
    visit root_path
end
```

with the following message

```
 Failure/Error: HomeController.should_receive(:index)
   (<HomeController (class)>).index(any args)
       expected: 1 time
       received: 0 times
```

? Is it because the index method is called as a instance method instead of a class method?

Comment: Assuming that spec is under your **spec/controllers** directory, try just changing the line to `controller.should_receive(:index)` and see if that works.

Comment: The spec resides in spec/request and I prefer that it be a request spec. And no, it does not work in spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb even after the change: controller.should_receive(:index)
       (#<HomeController:0x00000004989e10>).index(any args)
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to test, and I think there's some confusion as to what methods can be used where, so I'll try and give examples of [Routing specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-13/docs/routing-specs), [Request Specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-13/docs/request-specs/request-spec), [Controller specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-13/docs/controller-specs),  and [Feature specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-13/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec), and hopefully one of them will be appropriate for you.

#### Routing

If you want to make sure that your root path gets routed to the `home#index` action, a routing spec may be appropriate:

**spec/routing/routing_spec.rb**

```
describe "Routing" do
  it "routes / to home#index" do
    expect(get("/")).to route_to("home#index")
  end
end
```

#### Request

If you want to make sure that the `index` template gets rendered on a request to your root path, a request spec may be appropriate:

**spec/requests/home_requests_spec.rb**

```
describe "Home requests" do
  it 'successfully renders the index template on GET /' do
    get "/"
    expect(response).to be_successful
    expect(response).to render_template(:index)
  end
end
```

#### Controller

If you want to make sure that the `index` template gets rendered on a request to the `index` action of your `HomeController`, a controller spec may be appropriate (and quite similar to a request spec in this case, but focused exclusively on the controller):

**spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb**

```
describe HomeController do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "successfully renders the index template" do
      expect(controller).to receive(:index) # this line probably of dubious value
      get :index
      expect(response).to be_successful
      expect(response).to render_template(:index)
    end
  end
end
```

#### Feature

If you want to make sure the page rendered by `home#index` has some specific content, a feature spec may be appropriate (and also the only place you can use [Capybara methods](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master) like `visit`, depending on your Rails/RSpec version):

**spec/features/home_features_spec.rb**

```
feature "Index page" do
  scenario "viewing the index page" do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_text("Welcome to my awesome index page!")
  end
end
```

Comment: I see. So #should_receive works with #get but not #visit and must use the controller instance in HomeController. What I actually want to test is signing in through omniauth, which is why I want integration tests. The only thing I care about is that Sessions#create is called, and not where it is routed as I will redirect the user back to where he came from. It seems that the best thing is just to test the behavior in the Sessions#create method. Is that the most appropriate?

Comment: There's lots of similar questions about writing specs for Omniauth [on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rspec+omniauth) and guides at [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?search=omniauth) among others.  Have a look through those resources and see what is right for you.

Comment: @user2191332 You should accept Paul Fioravanti's answer, It is a great one

Comment: Would to deal with sessions when testing a controller , im getting the following `expecting <"dashboard"> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/d/users/sign_in>`

Answer (score 3):

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    my_method
  end

  def my_method
  end
end

describe MyController do
  it 'calls my method' do
    expect(controller).to receive(:my_method)

    get :index
  end
end
```